# Why is .NET Core container app running on AWS Fargate is very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, .net-core, aws-fargate

I am running a .NET Core web app on AWS Fargate and its very slow. Every requests takes a number of seconds to complete. I have create a simple controller/action inside it to demonstrate what I mean.

```
[Route("api/dealers")]
[ApiController]
public class DealersApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("locate")]
    public IActionResult GetDealersForModel(string postcode, string model, string dealerUniqueName)
    {
        return Ok(new object[0]);
    }

}
```

This is a sample controller I have. It returns a response within a milli second on my local machine but hosted in AWS Fargate it takes 2 seconds to return a response and its not doing anything inside. Did I configure something wrong? I have playing around with memory and CPUs but thats not helping either.

Comment: network latency I would say.
I'm working with fargate for almost a year and really love it as a simpe docker environment for .net core

Comment: I have used fargate with .net Core and next experience this delay. Did you check your hosting region? are you consistently getting this latency or first time ? Create new cluster to see if issue persists ?